# Analytic solution to recursive matrix normalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrence-relations

#### Problem

Consider a square matrix $X$ having the property $\sum_{i} X_{ij} = \sum_{j} X_{ij} = x$, for some vector $x$. Now consider that $X$ is transformed to $Y$ like this (element-wise $\exp$ & $\log$):
\begin{equation}
  y = \exp{(\log{(X)}+R)}
\end{equation}
where $R$ is a random matrix that has the property $\sum_{i} R_{ij} = \sum_{j} R_{ij} = 0$.

I would like to scale rows and columns of $Y$ so that:  $\sum_{i} Y_{ij} = \sum_{j} Y_{ij} = x$.

#### Asymptotic Solution

In practice I have found that this can be achieved like this:
\begin{alignat}{3}
  Y^{(k+1)}_{ij} &= Y^{(k)}_{ij}   &&\times x_{j} \,\Big/ \textstyle\sum_{i} Y^{(k)}_{ij}\\
  Y^{(k+2)}_{ij} &= Y^{(k+1)}_{ij} &&\times x_{i} \,\Big/ \textstyle\sum_{j} Y^{(k+1)}_{ij}
\end{alignat}
which asymptotically converges (for the matrices I'm working with, not sure what relevant properties they have) for large $k$, incrementing $k$ by $2$.
However, it's evidently computationally inefficient and I suspect there is an analytical solution. Maybe something to do with Cauchy-Kowalevski theorem? Eigenvectors? Thanks,

Comment: Is this the matrix exponential / logarithm or are these functions applied componentwise? Your approach is similar to the Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm, which applies to the case where $x$ is a vector with all ones and $X$ has positive entries.

Comment: Thank you! From brief reading, it seems there is no analytic solution then? (and also some conditions for convergence which so far I've fortunately not encountered)

Comment: Oops sorry I did not answer your question about element-wise exp & log operations: yes that is what I meant.

Comment: Please clarify your question to reflect all this.

Comment: Done. Please note this question is cross-posted on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68805934).